# How to run the COPY and RUN command in same container?

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install java from the rpm file to docker centos image.

```
> Step 0 : FROM centos:latest
 ---> **34943839435d**
Step 1 : COPY . jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
 ---> **2055e5db6ae9**
Removing intermediate container 7ae13aaa4424
Step 2 : RUN chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin &&     sh jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
 ---> Running in **c4d6b63576bc**
jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin: jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin: is a directory
2014/12/16 06:03:34 The command [/bin/sh -c chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin &&  sh jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin] returned a non-zero code: 126
```

The error it gives seems to be because of the different containers. How to run command on same container?

Docker file is as below

```
FROM    centos:latest

# Install Java.
COPY . jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin

RUN chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin && \
        sh jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax of `COPY` is as follows:

```
COPY <src>... <dest>
```

So `COPY . jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin` mean copy current directory as `jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin`. Hence the error.

This should give you what you want:

```
COPY jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RUN command is actually running in the same container, the command itself simply failed, probably because you did not set the path correctly.

Here is an example for a very similar docker file that builds and runs correctly (By the way, there is no need for /bin/sh -c, as this is exactly what the run command is doing)

```
FROM centos:latest

COPY test.bin /root/
RUN /bin/sh -c "chmod +x /root/test.bin"
```

For more info about the run command see https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#run